# How to fast forward all mails from roundcube to another mail?

Tags: email

People,

I want to know how i can automatically forward all the incomming mails, from Roundcube to a wxs(emailprovider) acount..

I hope this is a good explanation of my problem. I cant find it on the internet so thats why i want to ask it here.

Greetz

Comment: Roundcube is web frontend/MUA (Mail User Agent). If you want to forward mail automatically that is normally a function of the MTA or LDA (Mail Tranfser Agent or Local Delivery Agent).  So unless your roundcube install has ways of changing your local forwarding options, you will need to make a change on the mail server itself, and there are various ways of doing this dependent upon which MTA/LDA you are running.

Comment: Thnx for responding, i had contact with the company where i have registered my server.. and they explained to me that i needed to config the fastforward in the config of the server it self. Its works now.